# Spring: Ajax call to @ResponseBody param encoding fails in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, encoding

I'm working with Spring and try to make a ajax call to @ResponseBody in my controller.

**UPDATE**

Okay, I added the changes I got told to to my ajax settings.
My param "jtSearchParam" still has the same encoding problem in IE.
+ I got an other error, 406, the response Header has the wrong content-type.

Here's my new code

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json; charset=utf-8", produces="application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject getUsers(@RequestParam int jtStartIndex, @RequestParam int jtPageSize,
            @RequestParam String jtSorting, @RequestParam String jtSearchParam,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws JSONException{

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new UserExclusionStrategy())
                .create();

        List<User> users = userService.findUsers(jtStartIndex ,jtPageSize, jtSorting, jtSearchParam);
        Type userListType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();

        String usersJsonString = gson.toJson(users, userListType);
        int totalRecordCount = userDao.getAmountOfRows(jtSearchParam);

        usersJsonString = "{\"Message\":null,\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":" + usersJsonString + ",\"TotalRecordCount\":" + totalRecordCount + "}";

        JSONObject usersJsonObject = new JSONObject(usersJsonString);

        return usersJsonObject;
    }
```

So as you see I set the content type in `produces` but that doesn't help.
If i debug the response header it looks like this:
(That causes an 406 Not Acceptable from the browser)

[image: response header]

And my new ajax settings:

```
...
headers: { 
                 Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            mimeType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            cache:false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
...
```

**And my parameters still look the same in the IE!**

[image: IE debugged values]

Comment: does the jsp on which this code is being executed have a directive that sets a different encoding for the page?

Comment: @AkshaySinghal no it's set global like this: `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>`

Comment: why are you keep putting double qoutes on every property in the json object?!!

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy It really does the same as: 'Text' so that's not the matter

Comment: You can't do both writing to the response and returning something. If you want to change the headers you can return `HttpEntity<?>`. Since your returned `content-type` is not `application/json` I guess you don't have Jackson in your classpath.

Comment: @zeroflagL I'll try and change it into `HttpEntity`. I do have Jackson in my classpath but Spring does neither take `produces="application/json; charset=utf-8"` why doesn't it take that, this should actually change the response header...

Comment: `produces` is used to determine the most appropriate method for a request. I does not change anything.

Comment: @zeroflagL thanks for the suggestion with HttoEntity, even thought I changed into ResponseEntity, still you got me to the clue, see the answer below. But still, my request parameter still has the encoding problem in IE, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay the problem with the json content-type can be solved like this:

With ResponseEntity you're able to change the content-type of the response header, that way ajax can interpret the json object the correct way and you wont get an 406 Http-error.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> getUsers(@RequestParam int jtStartIndex, @RequestParam int jtPageSize,
        @RequestParam String jtSorting, @RequestParam String jtSearchParam,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws JSONException{

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new UserExclusionStrategy())
            .create();

    List<User> users = userService.findUsers(jtStartIndex ,jtPageSize, jtSorting, jtSearchParam);
    Type userListType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();

    String usersJsonString = gson.toJson(users, userListType);
    int totalRecordCount = userDao.getAmountOfRows(jtSearchParam);

    usersJsonString = "{\"Message\":null,\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":" + usersJsonString + ",\"TotalRecordCount\":" + totalRecordCount + "}";

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(usersJsonString, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The problem with the encoding can be solved like this:

IE won't encode your "ü, ä, etc." correctly, it'll just add it to your URL like this:"jtSearchParam=wü" but it should actually look like that:"jtSearchParam=w%C3%BC" (If it doesn't you'll get the encoding errors on your serverside when you use IE)

So where ever you add certain values to your URL, make sure to use the JavaScript method `encodeURI` on that value before you actually add it to your URL
Example:

`encodeURI(jtSearchParam)`

Comment: So who adds `jtSearchParam` anayway? `jTable` itself does not seem to have this parameter :)

Comment: @zeroflagL Yes i know, I added it myself cause I want to search in my usertable thought so :) If you want the code i can upload it.

Answer (score 3):

I can find conflict in the content type you are using between plain text and json

```
dataType: 'json'

contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

my recommendation for you to use json for all parts  `application/json` in header and content type also in the messageConverters you can just add jackson jars and it will convert the java object to json for you just you will need to change your return type `@ResponseBody String` to `@ResponseBody User` while User is an pojo bean contains getters and setters for your attributes.

Comment: I'll add these changes and see if it works then, thanks so far

Comment: @Bobo Zohdy  While your recommendation is good, I wonder where you see the conflict.

Comment: text/html vs application/json

Comment: @BoboZohdy `application/json` is not used by the OP anywhere.

Comment: @BoboZohdy See update above plaese, any idea why it still doesn't work + why I can't set the response content-type

Comment: 406 error is coming if the request you sent is wrong can not be parsed for example I got this error if I send below json {"name":"","age":16,}, could you print data before send in alert and past it here

Answer (score 2):

**The parameter encoding problem**

I can imagine two reasons why this is happening:

1. For some reason the browser thinks your page is not encoded in UTF-8
2. You have not included the `CharacterEncodingFilter`

The `CharacterEncodingFilter` solves most of the encoding problems that Spring users experience. It has to be the first filter in the `web.xml`.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you plan to use GET requests and use Tomcat ensure that the `Connector` element in your server configuration has the property `URIEncoding="utf-8"`. Other servers may or may not need a similar setting.

**The JSON return problem**

This is as easy as adding the `Jackson Mapper` to the classpath and `@ResponseBody` to the method's return type. In your case I suggest to create a `Message` class, that resembles your JSON response. In the simplest case your method could look like this:

```
   public @ResponseBody Message getUsers(int jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, String jtSorting, String jtSearchParam) {

      List<User> users = userService.findUsers(jtStartIndex ,jtPageSize, jtSorting, jtSearchParam);
      int totalRecordCount = userDao.getAmountOfRows(jtSearchParam);

      Message message = new Message();
      message.setRecords(users);
      message.setTotalRecordCount(totalRecordCount);

      return message;
  }
```

I deliberately omitted `@RequestParam` because it usually is not necessary when the parameters of the method have the same name as the request parameters.

If you use jQuery it hardly matters what the actual `content-type` of the response is, as long as the content can be succesfully parsed as JSON. Use `dataType: 'json'`,though, to prevent jQuery from making a wrong guess.

The `content-type` does matter, of course, if you use `produces`. If you don't need it to narrow down the request mappings I suggest to get rid of it.

Comment: the encoding filter is already existing in my web.xml and the call is a POST and either way my URIEncoding is set to utf-8 anyways. I'll sure take a look at your recommendation for the JSON solution, thanks so far

Comment: @JamesCarter For what it's worth: Your request is POST but that does not inevitably mean that the parameters are not part of the URL. Anyway, would you mind sharing the rest of your ajax call (i.e. the JavaScript code)? Maybe it helps finding the solution :)

Comment: It's all from a lib called JTable: http://www.jtable.org/ I actually just changed the settings. But the thing that confuses me is that it only doesn't work in IE, Firefox works like charm. IE still got an ASCI encoding as it seems like @zeroflagL

Comment: @JamesCarter The parameters you are using are all added to the URL by jTable. I guess that the URLs called by the browsers differ from each other. Could you check that? If that's true then it's probably the first reason given in my answer.

Comment: When i watch the request URL in the browser (via firebug) it's just fine really, but when i watch my params on server side the encoding fails in IE. In the POST url is really no difference from IE to FF, they look totally the same @zeroflagL

Comment: @JamesCarter So in both browsers the URL contains a part like "jtSearchParam=w%C3%B6" (=wö) and **not** "jtSearchParam=wö" (or wä, wü, whatever)?

Comment: @JamesCarter Just to be sure: When you right click on the page in IE and check the encoding: is it UTF-8?

Comment: @JamesCarter And could you check the URLs on the server side as well? You have the request in your method's signature so that should be easy.

Comment: IE:"jtSearchParam=wü" FF:"jtSearchParam=w%C3%BC" hmm you we're right, they're not the same, sry for that. So what's your approach to that then?

Comment: the URL on the serverside looks like that aswell: IE:"jtSearchParam=wü", FF: "jtSearchParam=w%C3%BC"

Comment: YOU'VE EARNED THESE +50 =D! I got the solution, see my accepted answer =)! THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure it is calling your json method, as perhaps there is another similar method which is returning text/html.

Comment: it sure is that method that is called, I debuged it many times checking if it could be an other one getting called, but it's not